# Django logging filter used at startup, but not during HTTP events

Tags: django

I have a Django project which produces a lot of useless log messages when static entities are fetched via HTTP GET.

I tried this in settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "filters": {                                 # <-- I added this
      'skip_static_media': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.CallbackFilter',
        'callback': do_skip_static_media
      }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "filters": ['skip_static_media'],    # <--- I added this
        },
    },
    "root": {
        "handlers": ["console"],
        "level": "WARNING",
    },
}
```

with

```
def do_skip_static_media (record):

  # This is for debugging only
  import sys
  sys.stderr.write (">>>do_skip_static_media:" +repr(record))

  msg = record.args[0]

  if msg.startswith ("GET /debughistory_sidebar/") \
  or msg.startswith ("GET /static/"):
    return False

  return True
```

What happens is that the log shows this during startup

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
>>>do_skip_static_media:<LogRecord: django.utils.autoreload, 20, /django-template-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py, 668, "Watching for file changes with %s">Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
```

but `do_skip_static_media` is not used during any HTTP requests.

How do I catch every HTTP event and filter those?

Comment: Try to set `root` logger's level to `INFO`

Comment: I don't want to filter all such things at the loglevel, I want to filter specific things.

Comment: Ah it was just to test it out. I currently have no way to test it on my own, but the root logger is configured to only process severity `WARNING` and above. Django http logs are most likely on a lower log level which gets ignored, and never reaches the filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `loggers` instead of `root` and the log level should be `INFO` for logging HTTP requests.

Please refer [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/logging/#django-logging-extensions) for more configuration options

Working example

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "filters": {  # <-- I added this
        "skip_static_media": {
            "()": "django.utils.log.CallbackFilter",
            "callback": do_skip_static_media,
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "filters": ["skip_static_media"],  # <--- I added this
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django.server": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": "INFO",
        },
    },
}
```